# Is a symmetric positive definite matrix always diagonally dominant?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, conic-sections, covariance

A Hermitian diagonally dominant matrix $A$ with real non-negative diagonal entries is positive semidefinite.

Is it possible to have a Hermitian matrix be positive semidefinite/definite and not be diagonally dominant?

In other words, if I know that a matrix $M$ is symmetric positive definite then can I ensure  $M - dI$, for a real number $d$, is positive definite only by ensuring $M - dI$ is diagonally dominant with non-negative diagonal entries?

I am aware that $d \le \lambda_{min}$, $\lambda$ being eigenvalue, for the matrix to remain semidefinite, but I need to avoid eigenvalue computation.

Thanks!

Comment: The matrix $\left(\begin{matrix} 1&-2 \\ -2&4\end{matrix}\right)$ is symmetric and positive semidefinite, but not diagonally dominant. You can change the "positive semidefinite" into "positive definite" by changing the $-2$'s to $-3/2$'s. Does this answer your question? (I am not totally sure what you are asking.)

Comment: Note: The converse direction holds. A symmetric matrix which is diagonally dominant is positive definite. I guess the same holds with "Hermitian" (no guarantees).

Comment: Thanks that answers my question

Comment: @darijgrinberg you wrote: 'A symmetric matrix which is diagonally dominant is positive definite.' This is only true if the values in the diagonal are positive. Diagonal dominance looks at the magnitude. For example $\begin{bmatrix}
-3 & 1\\ 
1 & 2
\end{bmatrix}$ is symmetric diagonally dominant but not positive definite.

Comment: @Hjan: thanks for catching this. I was using a nonstandard definition of diagonal dominance, in which the diagonal entries were required to be positive.

Answer (score 5):

This was answered in the comments.

> The matrix $\left(\begin{matrix} 1&-2 \\ -2&4\end{matrix}\right)$ is
> symmetric and positive semidefinite, but not diagonally dominant. You
> can change the "positive semidefinite" into "positive definite" by
> changing the $−2$'s to $−3/2$'s. Does this answer your question? (I am
> not totally sure what you are asking.) – [darij grinberg](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/586/darij-grinberg) Sep 30 '15 at
> 22:54